# How to use a Lambda in has_many association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to upgrade a Rails app, running on Ruby 1.9.3, to Rails 4.2.0 and I have an hard time updating an association.

Here the code I think I should use

```
has_many :current_roles, -> (role){ where(job_id: role.id)}, class_name:'Role'
```

I have seen the same use of a lambda in basically all the responses regarding association and Rails 4.2 around here.

However what I get it is `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end`

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby `1.9.3`, you can't have space between the arrow and the argument parentheses in a stabby lambda. So, it should look like this:

```
has_many :current_roles, ->(role) { where(job_id: role.id)}, class_name:'Role'
```

If possible, use a newer version of Ruby. `1.9.3` is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks. I plan to move to Ruby 2.2.3 once upgrade to Rails 4.2 is completed.